# Defective letter E in the giant linotype machine in Heaven

Tags: story-identification

Looking for author and title of a story in which a fellow has very peculiar things happen to him every 72 hours (or so).  He concludes the giant linotype machine in Heaven that is typsetting his life as he lives has a defective letter E.

Answer (score 49):

["The Angelic Angleworm"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62771) by [Fredric Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredric_Brown), first published in [*Unknown Worlds*, February 1943](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61837+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Unknown_v06n05_1943-02_slpn#page/n47/mode/2up) (click [here](https://archive.org/details/Unknown_v06n05_1943-02_slpn) for download options). (According to [this bio](http://www.thrillingdetective.com/trivia/brown.html), Brown started his career working as a typesetter and proofreader for the *Milwaukee Journal*.)

Charlie Wills explains the problem to the Head Compositor in Heaven:

> "Sure," said Charlie. "They're supposed to be perfect, so perfect that you don't even need proofreaders. But maybe once out of infinity something can happen to perfection, can't it? Mathematically, once out of infinity *anything* can happen. Now look; there is a separate typesetting machine and operator for the records covering each person, isn't there?"
>
> The Head Compositor nodded. "Correct, although in a manner of speaking the operator and the machine are one, in that the operator is a function of the machine and the machine is a function of the operator and both are extensions of the ego of—but I guess that is a little too complicated for you to understand."
>
> "Yes, I—well, anyway, the channels that the matrices run in must be tremendous. On our linotypes at the Hapworth Printing Company, an e-mat would make the circuit every sixty seconds or so, and if one was defective it would cause one mistake a minute, but up here—Well, is my calculation of fifty hours and ten minutes correct?"
>
> "It is," agreed the Head Compositor. "And since there is no way you could have found out that fact except—"
>
> "Exactly. And once every that often the defective e-matrix comes round and falls when the operator hits the e-key. Probably the ears of the mat are worn; anyway it falls through a long distributor front and falls too fast and lands ahead of its right place in the word, and a typographical error goes through. Like a week ago Sunday, I was supposed to pick up an *angleworm*, and—"
>
> "Wait."
>
> The Head Compositor pressed a buzzer and issued an order. A moment later, a heavy book was brought in and placed on his desk. Before the Head Compositor opened it, Charlie caught a glimpse of his own name on the cover.
>
> "You said at five-fifteen A.M.?"
>
> Charlie nodded. Pages turned.
>
> "I'll be—blessed!" said the Head Compositor. "*Angelworm!* It must have been something to see. Don't know I've ever heard of an angelworm before. And what was next?"

Comment: Is this the story you were looking for? If you are satisfied with an answer, you can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235